# Border around selected gallery image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a gallery of images for a user to select. I would like for the one they do select to be outlined with a border. I'm assuming this would be done with js but I'm unsure what it would like. Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="thumb_images" class="gallerycontainer" >
 <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><img src="../images/white.gif" width="75px" height="75px" border="0"at="white.gif" onclick="changePicture(this);" /><span><img src="../images/white.gif" /><br /></span></a>
 <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><img class="next_to_upload" src="../images/travel.gif" width="75px" height="75px" border="0" at="travel.gif" onclick="changePicture(this);" /><span><img src="../images/travel.gif" /><br /></span></a> 
 <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><img class="next_to_upload" src="../images/coffee.gif" width="75px" height="75px" border-radius="25px" at="coffee.gif" onclick="changePicture(this);" /><span><img src="../images/coffee.gif" /><br /></span></a>
 <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><img class="next_to_upload" src="../images/meditation.gif" width="75px" height="75px" border="0" at="meditation.gif" onclick="changePicture(this);" /><span><img src="../images/meditation.gif" /><br /></span></a>
 <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><img class="next_to_upload" src="../images/hobbies.gif" width="75px" height="75px" border="0" at="hobbies.gif" onclick="changePicture(this);" /><span><img src="../images/hobbies.gif" /><br /></span></a> 
 <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><img class="next_to_upload" class="next_to_upload" src="../images/fence.gif" width="75px" height="75px" border="0" at="fence.gif" onclick="changePicture(this);" /><span><img src="../images/fence.gif" /><br /></span></a>
 <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><img class="next_to_upload" src="../images/sheep.gif" width="75px" height="75px" border="0" at="sheep.gif" onclick="changePicture(this);" /><span><img src="../images/sheep.gif" /><br /></span></a>
 <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><img class="next_to_upload" src="../images/flower.gif" width="75px" height="75px" border="0"at="flower.gif" onclick="changePicture(this);" /><span><img src="../images/flower.gif" /><br /></span></a>
 <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><img class="next_to_upload" src="../images/motivation.gif" width="75px" height="75px" border="0" at="motivation.gif" onclick="changePicture(this);" /><span><img src="../images/motivation.gif" /><br /></span></a>
 <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><img class="next_to_upload" src="../images/blurredlights.gif" width="75px" height="75px" border="0"at="blurredlights.gif" onclick="
      changePicture(this);" /><span><img src="../images/blurredlights.gif" /><br /></span></a>
</div>

function changePicture(image) {
  var at = $(image).attr('at');
  var newpath = '../images/' + at;
  $("#img_prev").attr('src', newpath);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using CSS

```
a:active > img, a:focus > img , img:active, img:focus{
   border:2px solid #ccc;
}
```

---

If you want to do with JS (Add jQuery to your file)

```
$('#thumb_images').on('click' , 'a.thumbnail > img', function(){
    $('#thumb_images img').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

and in CSS

```
img.active{border:2px solid #ccc;}
```

Code 2: When you click on any images, the JS is going to add a class to the selected Image and again when you click else where it will remove all class=active from all Images and add class=active to the clicked image. Hope it helps

```js
$('#thumb_images').on('click' , 'a.thumbnail > img', function(){
    $('#thumb_images  img').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
img.active{border:2px solid #ccc;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="thumb_images" class="gallerycontainer" >
 <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><img src="http://a-z-animals.com/media/animals/images/100x100/temperate_forest.jpg" width="75px" height="75px" border="0"at="white.gif" onclick="changePicture(this);" /><span><img src="http://a-z-animals.com/media/animals/images/100x100/temperate_forest.jpg" /><br /></span></a>
 <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><img class="next_to_upload" src="http://gofoxfire.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/05-HAMILTON-FOREST-004-100x100.jpg" width="75px" height="75px" border="0" at="travel.gif" onclick="changePicture(this);" /><span><img src="http://gofoxfire.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/05-HAMILTON-FOREST-004-100x100.jpg" /><br /></span></a> 
 <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><img class="next_to_upload" src="http://gofoxfire.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/02-URBAN-FOREST-001-100x100.jpg" width="75px" height="75px" border-radius="25px" at="coffee.gif" onclick="changePicture(this);" /><span><img src="http://gofoxfire.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/02-URBAN-FOREST-001-100x100.jpg" /><br /></span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Edit: I realized that when I click somewhere else on the page, the border goes away. Is there a way to prevent this? I would only like the border to change when I select another image.

Comment: @ScottMyers code updated. Dont forget to add jQuery script to your html file

Comment: Oddly enough, the border doesn't go away when I select a different image. Any ideas?

Comment: can you update your question with what changePic fn does

Comment: code updated. It changes a larger preview of the image based on the selected image.

Comment: Ok added a snippet there was a typo `$('#thumb_images img').removeClass('active');` removed the `>` from the statement